# How to embed google map API in MATLAB?

Tags: image-processing, shortest-path, matlab

I want to embed google map api in my matlab application for finding shortest distance between two different location (co-ordinates). I tried to show poly line on it..

How can I achieve this in matlab ?

Thanks
Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB can natively instantiate *Java* classes. *Java* itself has been enhanced in order to leverage scripting languages. [How to Run Javascript on the JVM in Just Fifteen Minutes](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2007/07/javascript-on-jvm-in-fifteen-minutes.html) might be a valuable approach on using Google Map API from within MATLAB.

Comment: Can I add google map api directly in MATLAB by add DLL or reference of Google map api?

Comment: Instead of running the Javascript code (Google MAPS API) inside a browsers, it is executed in *Rhino*. I'm not aware of a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to use google distance matrix api and urlread in matlab.

try this:

```
orig_coord = '37.869733350860730,-122.284758688533';
dest_coord = '37.871700000000000,-122.253300000000';
mode='walking';

url = ['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=(',orig_coord,')&destinations=(',dest_coord,')&mode=',mode,'&language=en-EN&sensor=false'];

str = urlread(url);
```

then you can use JSON Parser to decode.

Comment: Thanks you Tom to give a another solution.